# "update smart group counts" button missing from manage groups

Tags: smartgroups

Wp 6.01 civi 5.51.1
as below. Standard Admin theme or Radstock

[image: Manage groups page]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any condition to hide the 'Update Smart Group Counts' link if you can access the Find groups search criteria field. Probably there must be some css or jQuery that is implemented via extension/module/plugin/theme to hide/remove the option. Can you check in inspect element if its hidden?